# Could not find method compile() error react native version .68+

Tags: react-native, gradle

I upgraded my project with using [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.4&to=0.68.0) from 0.67.4 to 0.68.0 And I saw that Gradle versions upgraded, too.

When I try to run `./gradlew clean` command in ./android file, it gives me that compile error.

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-i18n'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

To check it, I created new react native project with 0.68.2 version. On first run with npm run android command, application worked as expected. But after I install
[react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) package;

`npm install react-native-i18n --save`

and run `./gradlew clean` command again, it gave me same error again.

I replaced compile with implementation on ./node_modules folder and it fixed the error. But if I have lots of packages, should I replace all of packages' build.gradle files manually?

Root build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
            classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
            classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
...
```

gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15"
  }
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by editing the node modules of react-native-i18n package.

1. Go to **node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/build.gradle**
2. Replace **compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"**
   into  **implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"**
3. Save the file and run **react-native run-android**

You can use patch-package to make and persist changes to node modules.

This can be done by first making changes to the package inside node_modules and then running the following command, with  being the name of the package you just made changes to.

**npx patch-package** 
patch-package will then create a patches folder with a file inside, representing your changes. This file can then be commited to git, and patches can be restored later by running npx patch-package (without any arguments).

Optional step:

Add the following in the script section of your package.json to automatically patch the dependency when you execute "npm install".

**"postinstall": "npx patch-package"**

Comment: Sir you are a savior!!! thanks 

Answer (score 0):

- Where:
  Build file '..\node_modules@trackforce\react-native-crypto\android\build.gradle' line: 22
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':trackforce_react-native-crypto'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Change the code in that file error.

old `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

new `api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).